# Call mediator end point type(XPath)

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

In call mediator we can form endpoint  using XPath (from the response).But the problem is endpoint is not calling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/xpath" name="call"  
 xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET" protocol="http">
 <inSequence>
  <call>
 <endpoint key-expression="/root/a"/>
  </call>
  <respond/>
 </inSequence>
 <outSequence/>
 <faultSequence/>
 </resource>
</api>
```

following response is from postman.

```
<root>
<a>http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ca6db71340000132f76b192</a>
</root>
```

Expected response :

```
  <root>
 <name>abcd</name>
  <no>82382832</no>
  </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when using the resolving endpoint (using key-expression), we cannot give the URL directly [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Indirect+and+Resolving+Endpoints). We have to have the endpoint defined beforehand and should give only the key of the endpoint in the payload.

Secondly, for the key-expression to parse the xpath, the message should be built beforehand. Since call mediator is content-unaware, it will not build the message. Therefore, we should use a content aware mediator to build the message.

Following is the sample inSequence that'd work.

```
<inSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <call>
        <endpoint key-expression="//a"/>
     </call>
     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
```

Now the payload should be like

```
<root>
    <a>testEndpoint</a>
</root>
```

**Edit:**
The endpoint named 'testEndpoint' should be defined with the backend url.

You need to define an endpoint [[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Endpoints). For example, I'm using an [address endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Address+Endpoint).

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testEndpoint">
 <address uri="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ca6db71340000132f76b192">
    <suspendOnFailure>
       <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
    </suspendOnFailure>
    <markForSuspension>
       <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
       <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
    </markForSuspension>
 </address>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: sorry i am not that  clear could you explain with some practical code.. i tried by using registry but it not working for me .

Comment: Saving the endpoint in registry is optional. Please refer the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I receieved needed response in Postman, but you should use POST method as your request has a Body.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="call" context="/xpath">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="uri.var.httpendpointurl" expression="$body/root/a" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="{uri.var.httpendpointurl}"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

[image: Postman screeshot]